# How to change navigation bar display settings from flex to block for responsive displays?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code for a responsive navigation bar hamburger when the browser window shrinks. Currently, the navigation bar display is 'flex' but when I shrink the browser window for the hamburger to pop up, the links don't display in a list format (unless I change the display to 'block' for the navigation bar, which I don't want as a default code). Essentially, I want to know how to code for the navigation bar to change from 'flex' to 'block' when the browser window activates the hamburger. Here's the link to the site: http://staging1.oakpark.co/#contact

I'm working through the backend of Wordpress.

```
.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: .05rem solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-style: none;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;    
  }
}
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is your `hamburger  menu` ??

Comment: <div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
  <a href="#about" class="active">About</a>
  <a href="#lindsay">Lindsay</a>
  <a href="#contact">Branding</a>
  <a href="#contact">Photography</a>
  <a href="#contact">Instagram</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two same queries of 600px? you need to target the parent element where you set the display flex. In your case it's your navbar not the anchor tag.

```
.navbar.responsive { 
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vince. That worked. As for the two same queries of 600px, this is my first time coding so it's probably bad coding!